# How to obtain output from callback function?

Tags: matlab, time, callback, serial-port, serial-communication

Is it possible to get output from an instrument callback function in Matlab? I am reading data being sent to the serial port and a callback function is triggered when 1 byte becomes available

```
 s=serial('COM3');
 set(s,'BytesAvailableFcn',{@mycallback});
 set(s,'BytesAvailableFcnCount',1);
 set(s,'BytesAvailableFcnMode','byte');
```

I would like to record the exact time at which each callback occurs in a vector `T`. I am able to write the callback function such that I get a vector T, but I don't know to access T and it is not produced after the script has finished executing.

I could also have this vector T to be generated in the main script but I am unsure how to set the condition **if the callback occurs**. I previously thought that I could use `bytes=get(s,'BytesAvailable')` and if `bytes==1` I could have the time recorded in the vector. But `bytes` have value = 1 only once and then continues to grow.

I am aware that there is a function `record` which could automatically record the callback information:

```
 s.RecordMode = 'append';
 s.RecordDetail = 'verbose';
 s.RecordName = 'test.txt';
 record(s)
```

However whenever I try this, it does not record as I want it to. Although I set s.RecordDetail to `verbose`, the output in the .txt is the same if I had not set the RecordDetail.

Does anybody have any suggestions for this?

Thanks